# Tier Pricing Dropdown for Magento

Tags: php, jquery, magento

I have been working on a site for a number of months, and now am back to a feature that was never implemented.

We planned from the beginning to only allow people to checkout with our Tier-Price breakpoints as the incremental quantities available. All products on this site are custom, and stock is not kept.

We want the break points to reflect the tiers and not perfect increments (100, 250, 500, 1000, 2000, 3000, 5000, 10000) so the only way to set on a per product basis quantity limitation is choosing the set tiers.

The closest reference and code I found is below, it creates radio button options generated automatically from the tier breaks, but turning this into a drop-down has been more difficult then I thought.

If anyone can help out with the below code, I could just not get it to add all these options to a drop down, and dynamically change the price based on set quantity and options.

```
<div class="retail-price-contain tier-price-tab">
<?php
    $_tierPrices=$this->getTierPrices();
    $_firstTier = array_slice($_tierPrices, 0, 3);
    $c = count($_firstTier);
        if($c>0): ?>
        <ul class="tier-prices product-pricing">
            <?php for ($i = 0; $i < $c; $i++) {
               $_firstTierPrice = Mage::helper('core')->currency($_firstTier[$i]['price']); ?>
                <li>
                <input type="radio" name="tierprice" id="tier-price<?php echo $_firstTier[$i]['price_qty'] ?>" value="<?php echo $_firstTier[$i]['price_qty'] ?>" >
                <?php echo $this->__('Buy %1$s for %2$s', $_firstTier[$i]['price_qty'],'<span class="price">'. $_firstTierPrice.'</span>').$this->__(' each Save extra '.$_firstTier[$i]['savePercent'].'%');  ?>
                </li>
            <?php } ?>
        </ul>
<?php endif;  ?> </div>

<?php   
$_tierPricesqty=$this->getTierPrices();
$_firstTierqty = array_slice($_tierPricesqty, 0, 3);
$d = count($_firstTierqty);
if($d>0): ?>

<?php
  for ($i = 0; $i < $d; $i++) {
  $_firstTierPrice = Mage::helper('core')->currency($_firstTierqty[$i]['price']);  ?>

<script type="text/javascript"> jQuery(function($){     
    $("#tier-price<?php echo $_firstTierqty[$i]['price_qty'] ?>").change(function() { 
        $('#qty').val(this.value);
        //alert(<?php echo $_firstTierqty[$i]['price_qty'] ?>);     
    }); }); </script>
```

I put the above code in place of the following lines in mytheme/templates/catalog/product/view.phtml

```
<div class="qty-wrapper">
    <label for="qty"><?php echo $this->__('Enter Quantity:') ?></label>
    <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="18" value="<?php echo $this->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" /><span class="forinline">for</span>
</div>
```

and radio button tier pricing is working, but I could not modify this to get a dropdown without destroying functionality of the above code.

Can someone help modify this into a dropdown, I keep trying, but either am left with a non-functioning dropdown, or missing some options from the list (and the code above is missing 100 pieces).

Thanks, Alexander Countey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no Magento running atm. But i would think something like this should work:
https://jsfiddle.net/f7m5mp40/

```
<div class="retail-price-contain tier-price-tab">
<?php
    $_tierPrices=$this->getTierPrices();
    $_firstTier = array_slice($_tierPrices, 0, 3);
    $c = count($_firstTier);
        if($c>0): ?>
        <select name="tierprice">
            <?php for ($i = 0; $i < $c; $i++) {
               $_firstTierPrice = Mage::helper('core')->currency($_firstTier[$i]['price']); ?>

                <option value="<?php echo $_firstTier[$i]['price_qty'] ?>">
                    <?php echo $this->__('Buy %1$s for %2$s', $_firstTier[$i]['price_qty'],'<span class="price">'. $_firstTierPrice.'</span>').$this->__(' each Save extra '.$_firstTier[$i]['savePercent'].'%');  ?>
                </option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
<?php endif;  ?>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
jQuery(function($){     
    $("select[name='tierprice']").change(function() { 
        $('#qty').val(this.value);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: The above is working very well, but there is still two issue's, the base quantity/tier is not showing, in this case 100 pieces, and the price is not updated when selecting an option with the dropdown. I changed <select name="tierprice" > to <select name="tierprice" onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice();" >, which if tested in chrome developer tools or firebug works, but when put into the code is always one step behind (showing price for only the previous selection, not the current selection)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, exactly what I needed. I will figure out why the 100 peice default is missing, the issue above I have solved by changing onchange= to onclick=